# How do I split a list of objects that share a reference to the same class in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to split a list of objects by a specific criteria.

The criteria is that an object shares a reference to the same class.

This is what I have so far. I have a base class

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{  
}
```

and a child of that class

```
public class Snake : Enemy
{
    public List<snakePart> SnakeParts; 

    // A list of Snake Parts that this class creates and modifys
    // other general snake stuff like hissing etc etc
}
```

The snakePart class is mainly used to store data. It also creates GameObjects with BoxColliders and stuff in game.

```
public class snakePart : ScriptableObject
{
    private Color snakeColor;
    private int arrayIndex;
    private Snake snakeParent;

    // Create a new game object

    private GameObject createNewGameObject(int _arrayIndex, Snake _Snake)
    {
        GameObject newGameObject = // new game object stuff
        newGameObject.AddComponent<EnemyIdentifier>().identifierInit(_arrayIndex, _Snake);
        return newGameObject ;
    }
}
```

It attaches an EnemyIdentifier script to the game object it makes.
The purpose of which is to tell me who owns this particular gameobject.

```
public class EnemyIdentifier: MonoBehaviour
{
    public void identifierInit(int _arrayIndex, Enemy _owner)
    {
        ArrayIndex = _arrayIndex;
        Owner = _owner;
    }

    public int ArrayIndex;
    public Enemy Owner;
}
```

I have several of these snakeParts in my game ...and eventually I might also have dog parts, wolf parts etc. I fire something that gathers up a whole bunch of RayCastHit2Ds and turns that into a big messy list of references to these EnemyIdentifers.

```
List<EnemyIdentifier> EnemyIdentitys = new List<EnemyIdentifier>();



       foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in enemyHits)
        {
            EnemyIdentitys.Add(hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyIdentifier>());
        }
```

**What I'd like to know** is how in the 'EnemyIdentitys' list do I pick out any that reference the same 'owner'.

Add these to thier own list.

Repeat this until all EnemyIdentitys are in thier own lists based on if they are sharing an owner.

Thanks very much for taking the time to look at my question, and thanks in advance for any suggestions or code tips you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Agapwlesu I decided to use Linq.

Here is the solution

```
        if (enemyHits.Length > 0)
        {
            List<EnemyIdentifier> EnemyIdentitys = new List<EnemyIdentifier>();
            foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in enemyHits)
            {
                EnemyIdentitys.Add(hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyIdentifier>());
            }
            var groupedEnemyIdentitys = EnemyIdentitys
                .GroupBy(x => x.Owner)
                .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                .ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get a subset of the list by:

```
EnemyIdentitys.Where(x=>x.Owner == thisOwner);
```

or

```
EnemyIdentitys.GroupBy(x.Owner)
```

should give you a collection of lists, each list having a different owner.
That uses LINQ, so you will need to include it:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If you do not use Linq, you'd have to create your own code that partitions the list into sublists.  In that case, it might be better to have stored the data in a different structure to begin with.  If you have a list of Owners, add to each Owner the EnemyIdentitys that they own.

Comment: LINQ support in Unity is very, very bad. I'd not do this.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Did not notice the unity tag.  Not familiar with it.  Jim, if Unity does not support LINQ properly, skip this solution.

Comment: You could just add a solution below using a foreach loop?

Comment: Unity supports LINQ, I'm not sure why cFrozenDeath suggests that. thanks for the help Agapwlesu

Comment: I would expect that Unity uses Microsoft's compiler, even if they do have their own c# libraries and IDE.  It is one thing to develop libraries and an IDE, it's a whole other game to develop a language compiler for something like C#.  So I am not surprised Unity supports LINQ.  He may have been working with an older version of Unity that did not include the latest compiler.